# Overflow-x visible and overflow-y hidden with elements protruding beyond that have relative positioning

Tags: html, css, css-float, overflow

I have the following [structure and styles (CodePen)](http://codepen.io/expeerd/pen/RRvagG)

```css
.wrap {
  width: 50%;
  margin-left:  25%;
  background-color: red;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  padding-top: 16px;
  padding-bottom: 16px;
  
}
.content {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  position: relative;
}
.toggle {
  position: absolute;
  height:  32px;
  width: 32px;
  background-color: cyan;
  border-radius:  16px;
  top:  calc(50% - 16px);
  right: -16px;
  z-index: 10;
}
.border {
  height: calc(100% - 10px);
  width: calc(100% - 10px);
  border: 5px dashed purple;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrap'>
    <div class='content'>
      <div class='toggle'></div>
      <div class='border'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='content'>
      <div class='toggle'></div>
      <div class='border'></div>
    </div>
</div
```

I need to have both upper and bottom paddings in wrapper with floating elements. To do it I've added `overflow-y: hidden;` but `<ul>` have scrollbar. According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421966/css-overflow-x-visible-and-overflow-y-hidden-causing-scrollbar-issue) this is due to `overflow-x` behavior. But solution with additional wrapper doesn't work for me maybe cause of relative positioning of toggle.

Is there any solution, preferably without deep changes in structure?

UPD: `div.wrap` are in `<li>` that is in list with many items with the same content so absolute positioning isn't possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should clear the `float` that you are applying inside `wrap`. Also remove the `overflow` that you are applying and there you go!

Please let me know your feedback. Thanks!

```css
.wrap {
  width: 50%;
  margin-left:  25%;
  background-color: red;
  padding-top: 16px;
  padding-bottom: 16px;
  
}
.content {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  position: relative;
}
.toggle {
  position: absolute;
  height:  32px;
  width: 32px;
  background-color: cyan;
  border-radius:  16px;
  top:  calc(50% - 16px);
  right: -16px;
  z-index: 10;
}
.border {
  height: calc(100% - 10px);
  width: calc(100% - 10px);
  border: 5px dashed purple;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrap'>
    <div class='content'>
      <div class='toggle'></div>
      <div class='border'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='content'>
      <div class='toggle'></div>
      <div class='border'></div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div
```

Comment: I need `float` to align elements inside in one row.